# how to execute commands Using c# program Without using System.Diagnostics.Process class

Tags: java, c#, process, cmd, command

I want to execute cmd commands and java jar files from c# program without using `System.Diagnostics.Process` class. I searched in google but i didn't find any solution. Any one can help me to solve this problem.

I tried this code :

```
 Process cmdProcess = new Process
                    {
                        StartInfo =
                        {
                            FileName = "cmd.exe",
                            Arguments = " /K C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\JavaApplication1.jar",
                            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                            Verb = "runas",
                            UseShellExecute = true
                        }
                    };
                    cmdProcess.Start();
```

this is worked in windows 8 and 8.1 but in windows 7 i am getting Access is denied error.

Thanks,

Comment: Please provide a context to understand why you don't want to use `Process`.

Comment: If i use System.Diagnostics.Process in windows 7 i get access is denied error, even though i executed commands with admin privileges. so i want to execute commands without process class.

Comment: Thanks @kumar this link is not related to my question.